# Login with UPN name in windows 2008 server R2

Tags: windows, active-directory, rdp

Is it possible to login with same username but different suffix in windows 2008 R2?

Example: user1 with username abc@xyz.com abd user2 with username abc@gmail.com log in simultaneously using RDP.

Note: Username is same, only suffix part is different.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: As long as the `upnSuffix` is registered in the AD forest...

Comment: How profile will be created in windows?  With domain name or only with username?

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you set their AD UPNs to be abc@xyz.com and abc@gmail.com, respectively, it will work fine. Contrary to Michael's comment, you don't need to register any UPN suffix values for this to work.

Comment: So, users home (profile) directory will be created with abc@xyz.com instead of abc?

Comment: No - this will be two different user accounts. The profile directory name is driven by the `sAMAccountName` value.